# Can you refuse access to views with Pug/Jade conditionals?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pug

For example, a verification email info page. Anybody can currently visit www.mysite.com/verified and see the thank you message. Is there any way I can use conditionals to stop people from being able to view this page?

Thanks.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I would consider this an answer but you commented instead. I have it set up so when the user creates an account, he is sent to the thank you page. I don't necessarily need to block it. However, there are some other pages such as password reset I would like to block. Thank you for the answer. Is there any way I could of made this question more specific? If so, please let me know. Again, thanks.

Comment: Providing a little bit more detail on what you're trying to achieve  --- I.e. what is this verification for? Is it a login or a subscription. Why is it a problem to see the thank you message? What are you going to show instead? How do you identify unique users? What is your current code that you have tried and what documentation page have you tried looking at? (I'll admit pug's documentation is a little difficult to maneuver sometimes).   The main point is you don't want to leave out anything in your entire process because it can affect the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller you should render the correct template for authorized/unauthorized, utilizing the verification url id.

In the pug template, you could theoretically render or not render the template by simply using an if-statement on the entire template, but I personally wouldn't go about it this way.

```
- if (allowUser)
  .body
    .myhtml
- else
  .body
    .notallowed
```